# Trouble getting simple flex example to work

Tags: c++, c, flex-lexer

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html), and I am currently stuck on the first snippet of code:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
%}
%%
[ \t\n]         ;
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+  { cout << "Found a floating-point number:" << yytext << endl; }
[0-9]+          { cout << "Found an integer:" << yytext << endl; }
[a-zA-Z0-9]+    { cout << "Found a string: " << yytext << endl; }
%%
main() {
    // lex through the input:
    yylex();
}
```

Which first gave me an error because of the lack of return type for main so changed the code to this:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
%}
%%
[ \t\n]         ;
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+  { cout << "Found a floating-point number:" << yytext << endl; }
[0-9]+          { cout << "Found an integer:" << yytext << endl; }
[a-zA-Z0-9]+    { cout << "Found a string: " << yytext << endl; }
%%
int main() {
    // lex through the input:
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
flex snazzle.l
```

works fine, but when I do the next step:

```
g++ lex.yy.c -lfl -o snazzle
```

It says:

> clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
>   ld: library not found for -lfl
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What is going on? I am using `flex 2.5.35 Apple(flex-31)`, if it matters... Thanks.

Comment: You should tell `flex` to generate C++, I think the option is `-+`. However in trying to run your coed I get other errors. Sorry this isn't a complete answer. Good luck.

Comment: Same here, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang is complaining that the filename is lex.yy.**c** but you are compiling it with "`g++`" (how that gets to be `clang++`, I don't know, but it will be something to do with the toolchain Apple distributes; it's probably a symlink.) Doing that is, as the warning says, deprecated. None of that has anything to do with `flex`. You can tell flex that you want to output a c++ file:

```
flex -o lex.yy.cc snazzle.l
```

Although personally, I'd name the output file something snazzlier, like `snazzle.lex.cc`. Whatever you name it, it should end with `.cc` to mark it as a C++ file. Or you can use `.cpp` or `.cxx` or `.c++` or some other extensions I don't remember.

The second error is telling you that the `flex` library, `-lfl`, isn't installed, or at least it isn't installed in any of the standard places. Rather than try to find that library, I'd personally just add

```
%option noyywrap
```

to your flex input. Put it just before the fist `%%` line. That tells flex that there is no `yywrap` function, which in turns means that when the input file reaches EOF, it's really an EOF. `yywrap` is called when the input hits EOF, and it is allowed to change input files and return 0, indicating that the lex operation should continue. Obviously you don't need the feature for this tutorial -- it is only very occasionally useful, in general -- and the `fl` library includes a definition of `yywrap` which does precisely this:

```
int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

You could add that to your file instead, but it's just as easy to add the `noyywrap` option, in which case the generated lexer won't need a `yywrap` function at all.

Comment: Putting `%option noyywrap` and doing `flex snazzle.l` followed by `g++ lex.yy.c -o snazzle` seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the help (although it doesn't seem like g++ was the issue)!

Comment: @anon: The message about c++ is just a warning. For now. But you should get in the habit of naming your c and c++ files correctly. Glad it worked for you, anyway.

Comment: After putting %option noyywrap and doing flex snazzle, followed by g++ lex.yy.c -o snazzle, I receive this error: "use of undeclared identifier 'noyywrap'; did you mean 'yywrap'?"

Comment: @edap sounds like you put the `%option` line in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
Here is the solution : 
 1. Using lex.yy.cc instead of lex.yy.c as output file.

```
flex -o lex.yy.cc snazzle.l
```

2. Using ll flag instead of lf1

   g++ lex.yy.cc -ll -o snazzle